# In the Android sdk 8.0.7, is notification permission sent to the server whenever the application goes to foreground?

Tags: marketing-cloud, android, salesforce-sdk-android

The app was previously using 8.0.4, and this time going to update it to 8.0.7.

And as a result of checking the log, whenever change the notification permission of the app and bring the application to the foreground, `~/device/v1/registration` is requested, unlike 8.0.4.

As a result, if I did not bring the app to the foreground after granting the notification permission, push notification was not displayed.

Is this because updated to sdk 8.0.7? Or is there some code I didn't write in?

I'm sorry I'm not good at English.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

v8.0.7 supports Android 13 which requires a permission to display push notifications. Registrations will be updated when your application becomes active.

Comment: Thank you for answer.
Other OS versions also appear to update the notification settings of the application, such as Android 13, is this intended?